# Different formats for part in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am creating a TOC from the MWE below. I would like the part prefix which I have defined to not be applied to the introduction (see image). How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\Large\bfseries\scshape}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part} :\\\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\centering Part~}

% To Remove page number next to centred heading %
\newcommand{\gobbletocpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{\relax}}}
}%
\newcommand{\restoretocpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{\thepage}}}
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{part}{-1}
\gobbletocpage
\part{Introduction}
\restoretocpage
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\gobbletocpage
\part{This is part 1}
\restoretocpage
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's easier to do with `titletoc` (at least for me…).

Comment: The (wanted) result with the centered part entry looks very strange, doesn't it?

Comment: @Schweinebacke: With these parameters, yes, but I've seen nice-looking centred parts with horizontal rules above and below.

Comment: I just edited the MWE. I think it looks better with the page numbers removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of I never would make such a table of contents you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\Large\bfseries\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}:\\\hfill}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{}{\failed}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\addpart}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\hfill #1}%
  \part*{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addpart{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\part{This is part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{This is part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the page number at the part entries just add

```
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont[1]{}% remove page number
```

to get

[image]